# Stop scrolling to ID when opening jQuery Modal via URL

Tags: jquery, events, dialog, overlay, modal-dialog

I need to be able to open an ID'd jQuery UI Modal on a page when that modal's ID is passed in the page's URL.  For example:

```
http://mysite.com/visit.html#directions
```

#directions is an ID'd DIV at the very bottom of the page, right before the closing BODY element.  It's instantiated as a jQuery UI dialog on page load, then I'm running a function to check the current URL for the modal's ID.  If the URL contains the modal's ID, the modal is opened.

Here's what my auto-open function looks like:

```
function autoOpenModal() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#') ) {
        var uriParts = document.location.href.split('#');
        var hashID = '#' + uriParts[1];
        if ( $(hashID) && $(hashID).hasClass('dialog')) {
            $(hashID).dialog('open');
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the browser is automatically scrolling down to the ID at the very bottom of the page **before** the modal is opened.  So when the user closes the modal they're at the bottom of the page (which seems "broken" to me).

Can anyone tell me how I stop the browser from auto-scrolling down to the ID please?  I've had a look at `event.preventDefault()` but without success; I'm not sure where or how to use it in the event chain.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your URL "http://mysite.com/visit.html#directions" the web browser should always jump to "directions" as that is what is being asked of it. Instead of using "#" maybe you could use a query string.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false from within your `autoOpenModal()` function:

```
function autoOpenModal() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#') ) {
        var uriParts = document.location.href.split('#');
        var hashID = '#' + uriParts[1];
        if ( $(hashID) && $(hashID).hasClass('dialog')) {
            $(hashID).dialog('open');
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, karim.  But I tried that already and it doesn't seem to work.  I think it's because the browser "jumps" down through the markup before it executes the document.ready() event.